# can someone help me understand part of this block in RAILS 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io, foreach

I am learning excel/csv import in rails. I am watching this video by Ryan B.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

the following block is a bit confusing for me, I am unsure of some of the mechanics behind the second each loop.

```
model/page.rb

  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|      
      csv << column_names   
      all.each do |pages|  
        csv << pages.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

where did `all` come from? 
is it this method?
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/all/class

if so, what is `all` referring to? I understand that pages is a block variable, but where do the values for `pages.attributes` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` comes from [ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html). It's a class method that is basically saying get me all of the records for this model (`Page` in this case).

`attributes` on the other hand is an instance method that comes from [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html). It returns a `Hash` w/ the keys being the column names, and the values being their respective values.

Answer (score 1):

"all" is an alias for "Model.find(:all)", so it is getting all of the records for that model, ie all of the "pages" in your database, since you're in the "Page" model.

The "attributes" are the different attributes of that record, see here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes